# 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'EnableQuerySupport'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using InCubatize.Helpers;

namespace InCubatize
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            //1
            ////Create and instance of TokenInspector setting the default inner handler
            //TokenInspector tokenInspector = new TokenInspector() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) };

            ////Just exclude the users controllers from need to provide valid token, so they could authenticate
            //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //    name: "Authentication",
            //    routeTemplate: "api/users/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { controller = "users" }
            //);

            //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //    name: "DefaultApi",
            //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            //    constraints: null,
            //    handler: tokenInspector
            //);
            //end1


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
                           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApiWithActionAndTwoParams",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}",
                        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApiWithActionAndFiveParams",
                                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}/{id5}/{id6}",
                                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            //Old Code.
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.EnableQuerySupport();

            // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
            // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api



            var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
                Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;

            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the below Error:-

> 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'EnableQuerySupport' and no extension method 'EnableQuerySupport'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: I have checked the version of system.web.http and its correct.

Answer (score 10):

In Visual Studio go to "Tools" and then "Nuget Package Manager" and then "Package Manager Console"

Run the below command and it will fix the issue. Have tested it.

update-package microsoft.aspnet.webapi -reinstall

Answer (score 2):

> Note: This API is now obsolete.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj918506(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: use this instead:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.extensions.httpconfigurationextensions.addodataqueryfilter?view=odata-aspnet-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Check  System.Web.Http.OData.dll - this is where this method is coming from, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odatahttpconfigurationextensions(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Ok Now it has gone. Thank you. But i am getting the similar error for  "EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing" please let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: Note that this method is now obsolete.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.enablequeryattribute(v=vs.118).aspx